# Pig Hcatalog failed to read data from hive table

Tags: hive, apache-pig, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, hcatalog

```
grunt> table_load = load ‘test_table_one’ USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
grunt> dump table_load;
```

> 2016-10-05 17:25:43,798 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation – fs.default.name is
>   deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS 2016-10-05 17:25:43,930 [main]
>   INFO hive.metastore – Trying to connect to metastore with URI
>   thrift://localhost:9084 2016-10-05 17:25:43,931 [main] INFO
>   hive.metastore – Opened a connection to metastore, current
>   connections: 1 2016-10-05 17:25:43,934 [main] INFO hive.metastore –
>   Connected to metastore. … 2016-10-05 17:25:58,707 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   – HadoopJobId: job_1475669003352_0017 2016-10-05 17:25:58,707 [main]
>   INFO
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   – Processing aliases table_load 2016-10-05 17:25:58,707 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   – detailed locations: M: table_load[7,13] C: R: 2016-10-05
>   17:25:58,716 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   – 0% complete 2016-10-05 17:25:58,716 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   – Running jobs are [job_1475669003352_0017] 2016-10-05 17:26:13,753
>   [main] WARN
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   – Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig
>   to stop immediately on failure. 2016-10-05 17:26:13,753 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   – job job_1475669003352_0017 has failed! Stop running all dependent
>   jobs 2016-10-05 17:26:13,753 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   – 100% complete 2016-10-05 17:26:13,882 [main] ERROR
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil – 1 map reduce
>   job(s) failed! 2016-10-05 17:26:13,883 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.SimplePigStats – Script
>   Statistics:
>
> HadoopVersion PigVersion UserId StartedAt FinishedAt Features
>   2.6.0 0.15.0 hadoop 2016-10-05 17:25:57 2016-10-05 17:26:13 UNKNOWN
>
> Failed!
>
> Failed Jobs: JobId Alias Feature Message Outputs
>   job_1475669003352_0017 table_load MAP_ONLY Message: Job failed!
>   hdfs://mycluster/tmp/temp81690062/tmp2002161033,
>
> Input(s): Failed to read data from “test_table_one”
>
> Output(s): Failed to produce result in
>   “hdfs://mycluster/tmp/temp81690062/tmp2002161033”
>
> Counters: Total records written : 0 Total bytes written : 0 Spillable
>   Memory Manager spill count : 0 Total bags proactively spilled: 0 Total
>   records proactively spilled: 0
>
> Job DAG: job_1475669003352_0017
>
> 2016-10-05 17:26:13,883 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   – Failed! 2016-10-05 17:26:13,889 [main] ERROR
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt – ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator
>   for alias table_load Details at logfile:
>   /home/hadoop/pig_1475674706670.log

Can you help me to find why it is happening to me.?

Comment: try this   pig -useHCatalog

Comment: Looks like a issue with access, Can you check the logs of failed task on Yarn resourcemanager.

Comment: Grunt was started with pig -useHCatalog @ArunakiranNulu

Comment: Thanks, your answer gave me a lead to fixing this issue @vgunnu

Comment: @onlyvinish If you found the answer and think it is relevant for future readers, please summarize your solution and post it as an answer to help other visitors. If you think that it is not relevant, please delete the question to keep the site clean.

Answer (score 0):

Either use `pig -useHCatalog` or use `pig` and REGISTER the supporting JARS for HCAT to work with grunt.

You can find the required jars that are been shared into HDFS when you use `pig -useHCatalog`.

Answer (score 0):

```
grunt> table_load = load ‘test_table_one’ USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
grunt> dump table_load;
```

This may be the reason that you haven't created Hive table with the exact name. Check the hive table and schema for the same. 
**Before using Hcatlog we have to create table schema on top on the location from where we are loading the data.** uSE any queue name if require. Before executing please check for the table in hive.

Hope it will help. Try